# Logout from other devices in Laravel

Tags: authentication, laravel-8, logout, guard

I have a laravel system that has four different guards. I am intended to log out from all other devices if a user login from a new device or every login. I want to destroy all other previous sessions. I have tried all the suggestions found on the internet. Can anyone help me out with this issue?

```
if(Auth::guard('super_admin')->attempt($validated_data)) {
    Auth::guard('super_admin')->logoutOtherDevices($validated_data['password']);
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    return redirect()->route('super_admin_dashboard')->withSuccess('Login as Super Admin is Successful');
}
```

I have tried something like this. It works fine for login and changes the hash password in the database. But it remains logged on other devices.